# Update Access Database using Excel - best approach

Tags: vba, excel, ms-access

I have an Access Database and an Excel spreadsheet with a few hundred lines of data to update into the DB.  Some of the fields in the Access database are not in the Excel spreadsheet.

Is it best to write an Excel VBA script to update the Access DB or is there a better approach?

I am not very familiar with Access and my VBA skills are rusty so any examples are appreciated.

Some sample data, this is from the Excel:

```
    MN      File Identifier
587034901   PN000352
3248029409  PN000352
3066978806  PN000456
574565507   PN000477
```

MN would be the "unique key" in Access (I'm used to SQL).

These will be updates and not inserts.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your spreadsheet is "clean" and structured, I would find it easier to link your spreadsheet into your Access database. You can then update your Access data with a simple update query, since the list in your spreadsheet will appear like any attached table in Access.
By "clean", I mean:
 - consistent data types within a given column,
 - no blank row between the titles and the data
 - a single line of title

Comment: Thanks, I now have the data in another table in Access, I suppose that's half the battle!  So, now I just write an update query using Access, if this was SQL I could do that in a few seconds, now I need to find out how similar to SQL Access is.

Comment: If you know SQL, you can create a query in Access, switch to SQL View and just write your UPDATE. However I would suggest you try the graphical interface (Design View). It's very easy and you will avoid the specific syntax  Access SQL may have here and there..